# Only show one Datagrid tooltip at a time

Tags: vmware-clarity

Using the Clarity Datagrid, a user can open several column filters at a time, which can lead to the tooltips overlapping each other. Although I assume this is expected behavior, it does seem like a non-optimal solution.

Any insights on programmatically only allowing one tooltip filter open at a time?

[screenshot from the datagrid demo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLnJT.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that users can open more than one filter at a time is for UX purposes. When there are multiple filters applied to the dataset, opening multiple filters at the same time gives them a way to see all of the filter values if they need to.

We do have an [enhancement in the backlog](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1632) that will improve the filtering experience once it's implemented.

If you really want or need to programmatically manage the open / closed state of the filters you could add custom `clr-dg-filter`'s and tie into the `@Output` [clrDgFilterOpenChange](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.ts#L74). Alternatively, you could add a `#myFilter` template ref and grab it with an `@ViewChild` in your code to manage its open/closed state with the [toggle method](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/data/datagrid/datagrid-filter.ts#L91).